BEP-20 Token Total supply does not match the sum of all holdings
I have outsourced a minting of BEP20 token. (contract: 0xD83D23F1E07c139081Cb030154ae7C88f81238c1)
After a couple of transfers, the total supply (5billion) does not match the sum of all 4 holders balances (which is 100,000 tokens short).
There has been no burn, how could this happen?
I would appreciate any answers.
I haven't tried anything but to sum up the holders balances.
